# Drools Decision table rules not using updated values

Tags: drools, rule-engine, drools-flow

I am using Drools Rules Server as a service.  We are using a decision table

```
Pre Rules Movie Object:  
actor: "unknown"  
movie: "Ghostbusters"  
rating: 9
```

I have 2 simple rules in a Drools Decision table.   The 1st rule checks for a value (`movie=="Ghostbusters"`) and then sets the calls that objects `setActor("Bill Murray")`.

The 2nd rule checks to see what the Actor is.  I have 2 rows in this second rule.  `if Actor == "Bill Murray"` it calls an action of `setRating(10)`. And if `actor == "unknown"` `setRating(8)`

The first rule fires as expected, and I can printLn the `getActor` to show it's "Bill Murray" but in the second rule, the `actor == "unknown"` action always fires.  Even if in that row I print `getActor` it prints "Bill Murray" but it's using the "unknown" rule.

When the object comes back from the rules, it has `Actor = Bill Murray` and all values set in the rule "correct" but the rules seem to always use the original object I created outside the rule when evaluating rules.

Is there something I have to add to the decision table or the call to invoke the drools rule server to "update" the object between rule tables?

Comment: How did you structure your decision table? Can you post it here?

Answer (score 1):

I know too much time has passed since you asked the question but for others with the same problem:
As stated you should modify the object and not set it. To do this in decision tables add an action column in your RuleTable and in second line you should add:

`modify($className){ setActor("Bill Murray")};`

Keep the first row under action blank.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `update` or `modify` method as described in Drools docs (4.8.4.1, 4.8.4.2):

```
rule "modify stilton"
when
    $stilton : Cheese(type == "stilton")
then
    modify( $stilton ){
        setPrice( 20 ),
        setAge( "overripe" )
    }
end
```

this will tell the engine that object has been changed and rules will be reapplied.